# Nested Soql Queries in Trigger

Tags: trigger, soql, query

**My Question:
            **I want to Create a case Record,in that Case Record contact Lookup Relationship field is there,if i give some Contact in Case Record,that Contact act as a Portal User ,that Portal User Contact connects to Main User,in Main user LocalsidKey field is there,i have Created one custom field in case object called Locale that LocalesidKey value should Points to Locale in Case record when i am Created

How to Query the Localsidkey value from Portal User

```
for(case ce:trigger.new)
{
list<user> u = [select id from contact where ID IN(select LocaleSidKey from user)=:ce.contactid];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, within `Case`, you're limited to the fields available to you in the `Case` object. Case does have the `ContactId` field. However, a Portal User or Community User is still a `User`, ***not*** a `Contact`. In your situation, it's possible they may be the *Owner* of the Case or the User who *Created* the Case. It would depend on how your org is configured. Your org may be configured such that the `Community` or `Portal User` created the `Case` and the `contactId` was obtained from their `User` information. That's the assumption that I'm going to make.

Logic inside of Case trigger:

```
List<Id>cIds = new List<Id>();
map<Id,Id>case2ctc = new map<Id,Id>();
map<Id,string>cId2SidKey = new map<Id,string>();
map<Id,string>case2SidKey = new map<Id,string>();
for(case ce:trigger.new)
{
    // create map of cases to contactIds
    case2ctc.put(ce.Id,ce.contactId);
{

// query user to get SidKeys for contactIds (no subquery needed)
List<user>usrs = [select id, contactId, LocaleSidKey from USER where contactId IN: case2ctc.values()];

for(User u:usrs)
{ 
    //create map of results for contacts to LocaleSidKey
    cId2SidKey.put(u.contactId,u.LocaleSidKey);
}

for(case ce:trigger.new)
{
    //**if needed** create map of results for case to LocaleSidKey 
    case2SidKey.put(ce.Id,cId2SidKey.get(case2ctcce.get(ce.Id)));
{
```